# Changing an existing Entity Framework entity to become owned

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using EF 8.0.0.

I have two entities, `Exchange` and `ExchangeDay`, where the later has a reference to the former. I would like to change the model so that `ExchangeDay` is owned by `Exchange` but all my attempts at doing so have failed. Below is the original code before my changes.

```cs
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; }
}

public sealed class ExchangeDay : Entity
{
    private Exchange? exchange;

    public ExchangeDay(Exchange exchange, DateTime openUtc, DateTime closeUtc)
    {
        Exchange = exchange;
        OpenUtc = openUtc;
        CloseUtc = closeUtc;
    }

    private ExchangeDay()
    { }

    public Exchange Exchange
    {
        get => exchange ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Uninitialized property: {nameof(Exchange)}.");
        private set => exchange = value;
    }

    public DateTime OpenUtc { get; }

    public DateTime CloseUtc { get; }
}

public sealed class ExchangeDayConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ExchangeDay>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ExchangeDay> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.OpenUtc);
        builder.Property(x => x.CloseUtc);
    }
}

public sealed class Exchange : Entity
{
    public Exchange(string name, string timeZoneId)
    {
        Name = name;
        TimeZoneId = timeZoneId;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public string TimeZoneId { get; }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}

public sealed class ExchangeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Exchange>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Exchange> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Name);
        builder.Property(x => x.TimeZoneId);
    }
}

public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<AutoTraderDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    // This protected constructor is needed to allow sub-classes to call the
    // base constructor using their different generic DbContextOptions<T> instances:
    // (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontextoptions-versus-dbcontextoptionstcontext)
    protected AutoTraderDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    { }
    
    // ....
    
    public DbSet<Exchange> Exchanges => Set<Exchange>();

    public DbSet<ExchangeDay> ExchangeDays => Set<ExchangeDay>();
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(AutoTraderDbContext).Assembly);

        var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes();
        MapEntitiesToTables(modelBuilder, entityTypes);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private static void MapEntitiesToTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, IEnumerable<IMutableEntityType> entityTypes)
    {
        foreach (var clrType in entityTypes.Select(x => x.ClrType))
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(clrType).ToTable(clrType.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `ExchangeDay` entity already had an Id property I was hoping that changing it from a separate type to an owned type would go smoothly. I removed the `public DbSet<ExchangeDay> ExchangeDays => Set<ExchangeDay>();` from `CustomDbContext`, made the following changes to `Exchange` and tried to create a migration.

```cs
public sealed class Exchange : Entity
{
    private ICollection<ExchangeDay>? exchangeDays;

    public Exchange(string name, string timeZoneId)
    {
        Name = name;
        TimeZoneId = timeZoneId;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public string TimeZoneId { get; }

    public ICollection<ExchangeDay> ExchangeDays
    {
        get => exchangeDays ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Uninitialized property: {nameof(ExchangeDay)}.");
        private set => exchangeDays = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

The migration turned out empty, which made sense. I've tried numerous ways to update `ExchangeConfiguration` but there's always an issue. My last attempt was

```cs
builder
    .OwnsMany(x => x.ExchangeDays, y =>
    {
        y.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ExchangeId");
        y.Property<int>("Id");
        y.HasKey("Id");
    });
```

Creating a migration using the code above gave me the following error message: *The exception 'The entity type 'ExchangeDay' cannot be configured as owned because it has already been configured as a non-owned. If you want to override previous configuration first remove the entity type from the model by calling 'Ignore'.*

I then added `modelBuilder.Ignore<ExchangeDay>();` to `CustomDbContext` and tried to create a migration again, which gave the following error message: *Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'IbatDbContext'. The exception 'The entity type 'ExchangeDay' cannot be configured as non-owned because it has already been configured as a owned. Use the nested builder in `OwnsOne` or `OwnsMany` on the owner entity type builder to further configure this type. If you want to override previous configuration first remove the entity type from the model by calling 'Ignore'.*

I feel like I've tried multiple combinations of things without success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have a `DbSet<ExchangeDay>`

Comment: @MateusZampol "I removed the public DbSet<ExchangeDay> ExchangeDays => Set<ExchangeDay>();..."

Comment: My bad. You cannot configure an owned entity from outside the ownership definition. You have to remove your `ExchangeDayConfiguration `

Comment: @MateusZampol Ah, I see. Unfortunately removing the `ExchangeDayConfiguration` still gives the "Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'IbatDbContext'. The exception 'The entity type 'ExchangeDay' cannot be configured as owned because it has already been configured as a non-owned. If you want to override previous configuration first remove the entity type from the model by calling 'Ignore'." error message.

Comment: Then I assume it's breaking because the Entity is configured in a previous migration and you can't change it to owned in a new one. I think you need to create an intermediate migration where you only ignore the entity and then you can modify the model to make it owned in the migration you are currently trying to generate

Comment: A reasonable assumption since the entity was configured in a previous migration. I tried to create an intermediate migration, dropping the ExchangeDay table (making a copy of the data in a backup table first since I wanted to use it) and then updating the database. Sadly I still get the same "The exception 'The entity type 'ExchangeDay' cannot be configured as owned because it has already been configured as a non-owned." error message. I would love to solve but this but I have to move on. Got to settle on a "has-many" instead of "owns" relationship for now.